# Как реализовать нажатие на кнопку c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Это тестовая игра, 3 уровня, в который необходимо при нажатии на букву и цифры, чтобы уровень заканчивался.
1.Как это реализовать?
Через элемент массива или как?
2.Как сделать так, чтобы на следущих уровнях цифры с буквами не повторялись?

Что необходимо:
При старте игры:
-Буквы с цифрами пояляются рандомно при помощи массива.
-Сверху буквы и цифры задания тоже пояляются рандомно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Добавьте метки: язык программирования, используемый фреймворк и т. п.